# Why am I having communication issues between ESP12F and ATmega328?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, uart, esp8266, atmega328p

I am working on a PCB to enable an ATmega328 to connect to an MQTT network through an ESP12F. I am using a voltage divider in the TX line from the ATmega to reduce it to 3.3v (using nets SR+ and SR- for the communication,) but I am having difficulti to maintain the communication. Most of the time a power reset solves the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Attached are the schematics:

[image: ESP Side]
[image: ATMEGA SIDE]
[image: USB AND POWER SUPPLY]

1. How can I solve this issue?
2. what considerations i need to make while routing these communication lines.

Comment: Most likely AVR powered from 5V can't reliably receive 3.3V signals. Or a code issue. Why are you not running the AVR at 3.3V too? There is also a weird capacitor between CH340 V3 pin and 3V3 supply, what's the purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your power connections are incorrect.  The V3 cap should be in parallel if 5V is used. You are using 4.7V for some reason when the chip works down to 3V and you have a 3.3V regulator in series with a cap to V3.

You should have C8 going from 3.3V to ground and connect Vcc to V3 to 3.3V.

*Reset is a C-coupled output is a mystery or a mistake.

Comment: 1.I am not sure how to connect the V3 pin. I saw many different versions of the V3 connection (GND, 3v3, and 5V). so I made a 4 pin header with all possible connections for testing, if needed I can jump the capacitor

Comment: i got these schematic references from Arduino schematics so the RESET connection I got it from them, not sure about this

Comment: Recheck and list your sources in your question.  Obvious errors.

Comment: What changes i need to make if I want run completely in 3.3V

Comment: Do as I said....

Comment: @ShanuverIsniyakhTV When Tony says "Do as I said" he means that following the advice in his answer and comment is enough to achieve what you have requested.